# Winform to Crystal Report value changes

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

Why does a value from a certain Winform change when passing to a report?

for example from a form I have a string 1311-0015 but when I pass it to a Formula Field it becomes 1,296.00

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNj5H.jpg

Passing it to a TextObject doesn't change the value it's still 1311-0015 but I can't use TextObjects in formulas in Crystal Report.

Would like to know why this is happening and how to remedy the problem.

this is the code from the winForm:

> report.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["SOS"].Text = transactionId; ((TextObject)report.Section2.ReportObjects["Text3"]).Text = transactionId;

the value I was passing to the crystal report:

> public string transactionId = "1311-0015";

Comment: it sees it as a mathematical equation. Try putting it in quotes. Also paste your code so we can get a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: So the transactionID needs to be a number?

Comment: I have added in more details

Comment: Can you post the crystal formula? You won't be able to pass a number with a dash in it as a number.

Comment: It just needs to stay 1311-0015 when I pass it to the FormulaField but instead it changes to 1,296.00

Comment: even if the value I'm passing is a String?

Comment: Because it evaluates 1311 - 15 = 1296. So you need to figure out how to pass the value without it being evaluated. I think you will need to adjust your CR formula. Please post it if you can.

Comment: i don't have a CR formula i just pass the values

Comment: Well, that explains it then. You said you are passing the value to a formula field. If there is nothing in the formula, and you pass 1311 - 15 to the formula, it will evaluate it. Instead of a formula field, use a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You said you are passing the value to a formula field. If there is nothing in the formula, and you pass 1311 - 15 to the formula, it will evaluate it. Instead of a formula field, use a text box or modify the string so it doesn't come out like an equation. For your transactionID value try something like:

```
""1311" & "-" & "0015""
```

You may need to have two separate public string transactionId variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this string as parameter.
First, create a parameter field in you Crystal Reports editor. (Right button, New...)

[image: Parameter field]

Code something like this:

```
string transactionID = "1311-0015";

yourRpt.SetDatasource(youDataSource);
yourRpt.Parameters.SetParameterValue("transactionID", transactionID);
```

Now, you just need to drag and drop the parameter field into the report.

Comment: If I use parameter fields, there's always a parameter prompt that keeps popping up.

Comment: Don't use refresh, or set to re-use past parameter data.

Comment: Can't you use a dataset? I always use datasets to fill my report. But to small changes, i use parameters.

Comment: Did you tested without refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a parameter and use its value inside the formula. 
In order to avoid showing parameters dialog box make sure that the parameter value is set (you should do this in your code) and set: 
yourReport.EnableParameterPrompting = false;